# How to handle If else condition in rest assured

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Description: I have made two different class methods, setpassword and resetpassword. If my resultStatus and resultMsg is "F" and "PASSWORD_NOT_EXIST" in resetpassword class method, then i have to call set password method which is another class method , how can i handle this code by using if else condition

Response:

```json
{
    "response": {
        "body": {
            "resultInfo": {
                "resultStatus": "S",
                "resultCodeId": "0001234",
                "resultCode": "SUCCESS",
                "resultMsg": "SUCCESS"
            }
        }
    },
```

Code snippet:

```
r.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
r.header("reqmsgid", "133:1");
r.body(j.toJSONString());
response = r.post(apiUrl);
String myjsonobject = j.toJSONString();
System.out.println("Request body: " + myjsonobject);
System.out.println("Response body: " + response.getBody().asString());
int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
System.out.println("Response status code:  " + statusCode);

return myjsonobject;

if (response.jsonPath().getString("response.body.resultInfo.resultStatus")"F"){
     System.out.println("failure");
}
```

I want to handle this by using if else condition under resetPassword method

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this.

```java
//get the response from resetpassword
Response res = ...

if (requireResetPass(res)) {
   //call api setpassword
}
```

```java
private boolean requireResetPass(Response res) {
    return "F".equalsIgnoreCase(res.jsonpath().getString("response.body.resultInfo.resultStatus")) &&
    "PASSWORD_NOT_EXIST".equalsIgnoreCase(res.jsonpath().getString("response.body.resultInfo.resultMsg"));
}
```